# Python: ImportError: No module named 'database'

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, pythonpath

When I run my Python 3 project, I always get error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'database'
```

I have an empty `__init__.py` file in the database folder.
I am able to make it work if I run:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/youpath/myProject"
```

However, when I restart the system (Ubuntu), I get the same error again. How can I make it work in a permanent way?

Comment: Package up your project and install it. Your code will be installed to one of the existing places python looks for modules and packages. Python [wheels](https://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a good way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what Shell you are using.  If you are using bash add this to your ~/.bashrc

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/my/other/path"
```

I also tend to create "launch scripts" for many of my files as to not clutter my python path with too many paths as well as to gain a fine grain approach to what is available.  Below is a sample run_script.sh file I use

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<PATH VALUE 1>:<PATH VALUE 2>
echo $PYTHONPATH

python <path_to_script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to use a package or module permanently is to install it. You can install directly from your source directory by writing a `setup.py` file and install it by `python stup.py install` (see [distutils](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/2.0.html#distutils-making-modules-easy-to-install)). Or you can go all-in and build your own installation bundles with [wheels](https://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).